# Why is Tsukune allowed into the monster school in Rosario+Vampire?

Tags: rosario-vampire

So, Tsukune's father finds a school admission letter someone drops, and gives it to Tsukune. And then Tsukune goes into a monster school, and the magic to stop humans doesn't work, and he becomes a normal student. Am I the only one who finds this weird?

Is there any reason he was allowed in the school? Surely the teachers/headmaster would realize he is not a monster, and that he is using someone else's admission letter?

Answer (score 6):

The trick to this is, that noone in the school knows he is human except

> the headmaster, who dropped his letter of admission in the first episode

and maybe the bus driver, who is revealed to be:

> Nurarihyon the supreme commander of all monsters in the last episode of the 2nd season manga.

additionaly to the end of Capu 1 (it's their Season)

> he almost dies and Moka Akashiya turns him into a part-vampire to save his life

The plot device used for this is, that in School no one is allowed to show their true form, but have to disguise as humans. This allows him to wander freely in this school for monsters.

At the same time of the revelation on who the Bus Driver is, the true reason is also revealed:

> Nurarihyon (aka the Bus Driver, aka the supreme commander of all monsters) wants Tsukune to be the next headmaster of the school of monsters.

Comment: Vogel, this still doesn't answer the why part, which was my question

Comment: this is never explained anywhere in the anime. haven't checked the manga though. i would think, that the headmaster wishes for some personal entertainment by purposely admitting a human to his school of monsters.

Comment: Not explained in the manga either. It's implied that Tsukune is not normal, and if anyone knows about it, they're not talking.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't finished the manga, the text below may be a spoiler.

> Okay, there is a reason - in the last 2-3 chapters of the manga, it was revealed that Tsukune was allowed to become a vampire to fight against Alucard, and I think that it was implied that he was supposed to be a middle man for negotiations between the two in the future in the beginning.

Comment: Alucard was a vampire in another Manga/Anime- Helsing I think. Are you sure you haven't gotten your Mangas confused?

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari that is not correct. Alucard also shows up in Rosario+Vampire.

Comment: Since the revelations in the epilogue of Capu 2 as of the manga, this answer is plain incorrect... Please update your answer to incorporate the "latest" developments.

Answer (score 0):

It was revealed that the headmaster purposely drop the school admission letter and had planned to turn tsukune into a shinso vampire in the hope that tsukune could defeat Dracula one day, which technically happened even though Dracula voluntary admitted defeat and killed himself

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Can you provide a reference (episode/chapter number) for when this is revealed?